# Are there any issues with my plan to install Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox

Ok, I have a PC with a Core i3 processor, 12GB Ram, 750GB Hard Drive and an adequate Nvidia graphics card and 2 24" monitors.

I want to install Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit edition, install VirtualBox and put a 32bit copy of Windows 7 inside a VirtualBox instance. I want to allocate my Windows instance 2 of my four threads and 4GB of my ram. Then I want to install guest additions, turn on seamless mode and have my Windows taskbar sitting on the bottom of my second screen.

I can't see any issues with my plan but I'm all for constructive criticism so please let me know what you think.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  This is not intended to be an opinion-based discussion forum.  If you have any specific questions about specific problems with your setup we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue with the plan. If all the hardware, especially your nvidia driver, work, then you should be good. And since you have so much ram, you can allocate 4 GB for windows 32bit